# Map 1d numpy array to 2d array based on element-wise function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, it has `shape=(10000,)`.  Here are the first 5 entries:

```
labels = data[:, 0]
print(labels.shape)
print(labels[0:5])

# prints 
# (100000,)
# [1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
```

Every entry is either 0 or 1.  I would like to map this to a 2d array, by an element wise operation which maps

```
0 -> [1, 0]
1 -> [0, 1]
```

How do I do this?  I tried

```
labels = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [1, 0] if x[0] == 0 else [0, 1], 0, data[:, 0])
```

but that did not seem to work.

Comment: In the future, if you get stuck on a problem like this, you can always do things the dumb way—built each column (`1-labels` and `labels`) and stack them. (And of course you can do that temporarily, just so you can get on with the next step in your code, while you wait to see if someone has a better answer on SO.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [435]: ref = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
In [436]: index = np.array([1.,1.,1.,0.,1.])
```

Indexing with floats gives an error in recent versions:

```
In [437]: ref[index,:]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-437-d50c95668d6c> in <module>()
----> 1 ref[index,:]

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Index with integers, select rows from `ref` depending on the `index` value:

```
In [438]: ref[index.astype(int),:]
Out[438]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

This is a case where `choose` could be used, but it's pickier about array shapes than the above indexing:

```
In [440]: np.choose(index.astype(int)[:,None],[[1,0],[0,1]])
Out[440]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

or with only 2 choices that convert to boolean, `where`:

```
In [443]: np.where(index.astype(bool)[:,None],[0,1],[1,0])
Out[443]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following

```
labels = np.array([1,1,1,0,1])
np.eye(np.max(labels) + 1)[labels]
```

which gives:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This method does xor on the original array and stack two arrays together.

```
labels = np.random.randint(0,2, 10000)
# array([0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0])
np.vstack([(~labels.astype(bool)).astype(int), labels])
array([[1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0]])
```